# How to create a stored procedure with schemabinding?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure with schemabinding but I am unable to do so.

Error:

> An invalid option was specified for the statement "CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE"

Is it even possible to create stored procedures with schema binding?

```
create procedure dbo.proc_GetIncome  (
@fromdate datetime,  
@todate datetime  )
with schemabinding
as  
begin
declare @from varchar(8)  
declare @to varchar(8)  

select @from = YEAR(@fromdate) * 10000 +MONTH(@fromdate) * 100 +DAY(@fromdate)  
select @to = YEAR(@todate) * 10000 +MONTH(@todate) * 100 +DAY(@todate)  

select accountid , las.acctnm ,sum(amt) as Amount from nbfcledger led left join tbl_LASClientmaster las on led.AccountID=las.LasAcctNo  
  where glcode='INTRND' and dr_cr='d' and     
valuedate >= @from and valuedate <= @to  
group by accountid,las.acctnm   
end
```

Comment: What version of server do you have?

Comment: @Igor ms sql server 2008

Comment: "Normal" T-SQL stored procedure don't support schemabinding - only "views" have a schemabinding option in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: as you can see in books online there is no SCHEMABINDING-Option for Stored Procs in SQL-Server 2008 https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms187926(v=sql.100).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When talking about stored procedures, `schemabinding` is only supported by, and required for [natively compiled stored procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn452286.aspx) which were introduced only in SQL Server 2014.

That is why you are getting the error in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I was not aware of that. Thank you. Btw is there any work around? 
I would like to prevent anyone from making any change in tables that have been used in this procedure such that it makes the procedure non-functional.

Comment: @Arbaaz The only way I know, is to deny `ALTER` permission for this tables.

Comment: `WITH SCHEMABINDING` is also used for `FUNCTION` and `VIEW` objects, not just nativly-compiled procedures.

Comment: @Dai thats true. I meant that somewone can use schemabinding for stored procedure if it is natively compiled. Now I see that the answer can be misunderstood.