# Validate that referenced tables exist when creating a procedure

Tags: sql-server

SQL Server only seems to validate that a procedure contains valid T-SQL and that all columns referenced for existing tables are valid. Meaning that I can create a procedure that references non-existent tables.

So, how might I verify that only existent tables are referenced?

Please note that I do not care about dynamic SQL in this case as I believe that would be out of scope.

Comment: How about you just run it?

Comment: Views can have a `SCHEMABINDING` option, but stored procedures can't. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34063123/how-to-create-a-stored-procedure-with-schemabinding

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that it does NOT validate if the tables, views or other objects exist. This is known as deferred name resolution. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190686.aspx

The only way I know of to validate the objects actually exist is to execute the procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will not check, but some of MVP's posted feature for this...

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/260762/add-optional-checks-for-more-robust-development

Answer (score 1):

You can actually make use of SSDT tool in visual studio so that the once you create a procedure that actually refers a non existent table, then the Visual Studio gives a warning

Answer (score 1):

Deferred name resolution is a SQL Server "feature" in there for convenience as it allows development to be done "out of order". But it does allow invalid objects to slip in there.

Redgate SQL Prompt (commercial tool) has a Find Invalid Objects feature that will list objects that reference objects that don't exist.

It has a 14-day trial so feel free to download it and give it a go. If it doesn't spot the objects you expect it to, do let us know!

Answer (score 0):

Query the database system's "tables" table.

After connecting to the database, use this to view all tables in the database.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables
```

Use this to view a specific table.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name='<YourTableName>'
```