# How to find column names which used for joining tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing, stored-procedures, dependencies

I have a stored procedure for a select query and there are left join and inner join commands in the query. I'm using the script below for dependencies of the stored procedure.

```
select  
    referenced_database_name,
    referenced_entity_name,
    referenced_minor_name
from 
    sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.sp_test', 'OBJECT')
```

How can I get the column name which used for joining tables in this SP? Or is there any simple way to get/parse column names from this script:

```
select column1, column2
from tableA
inner join tableB on tableB.id = tableA.id
```

I need `tableB.id` and `tableA.id` keywords from the script

I've tried parse that script with `substring`, `left` etc functions but they're insecure for me. There are lots of piece of select query using union all.

Comment: Are your join columns not already part of referential integrity (foreign key constraints)?

Comment: If you want to know what columns are part of your join predicates you should look at the query. But this sounds like an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) to me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Yes they are foreign key and primary key columns but I cannot use constraints in the table. So i have to get that info manually

Comment: How can they be foreign keys but you can't use constraints? That is contradictory. Either they are foreign keys (meaning there is a foreign key constraint in the database) or they are not foreign keys.

Comment: Are there foreign key relationships or not? Can you not rely on getting the _likely_ join columns from the metadata? What are the odds two tables are joined on something _other_ than the foreign key columns? Parsing query text is cumbersome and imprecise, so maybe you could better explain exactly what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @SeanLange i can create foreign key and primary key using that columns in the table but i dont  want to do this.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thank you i know its  a cumbersome and imprecise way to parsing query text but it looks there is no way to do it with another way. There arent any relationship in the table physically

Comment: @Ufuk are you perhaps trying to enforce that the schema is not changed in such a way that would cause the sproc to fail? If so, this answer might pertain to what you are doing - https://stackoverflow.com/q/34063123/352349. In any case it would be good to add some more reasoning to your question, it may be an XY problem like Sean said above.

Comment: @Anssssss: I think can't explain my problem with my bad english. I will try to solve it myself. Thank you

Comment: @Ufuk, I'll just throw out one other breadcrumb in case it is useful to you - if you can do your query in a view, SQL Server does maintain information about what columns are used in what tables for a view. It wouldn't be specific to just what was used in a JOIN, but maybe it will help you. 
`select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE`

Comment: I appreciate your efforts @Anssssss but it doesnt enough for me. Well i'v just solved my problem with parsing the query. I wrote a code below for which columns used for join

Comment: Why do you not want primary and foreign keys defined in your database? Are you trying to ensure your data is a mess and the performance is slow?

Comment: @SeanLange Yes my data is mess and total database size is very large. Also most of data is read only and updated several times a day. So I dont need to create foreign keys and primary keys.

Comment: How can you say the data is readonly and also updated several times a day? And why do you think you don't need primary or foreign keys? Do you not query this database?

Comment: @SeanLange Im trying to say that database using for only querying and analyzing the data. Its like an OLAP or DW. There are lots of sources to feed database but there isnt any application connecting to database. There is no frequently occurring transaction. I I have very large size databases which i said before. One of them takes up 2tb in disk and has 3-4 billion rows for example. If i create foreign keys and primary keys. This affects the query performance bad i think. doesnt it?

Comment: Well your don't necessarily need a primary key but they do need a clustered index. And a foreign key is not going to make a select query any slower. The performance there would be for inserts, updates and deletes.

Answer (score 0):

I'v solved my problem parsing the query. At first, i left a delimiter (--*) for splitting the section which contains joins then used that code for parsing the query (i know its not professional but it has worked for me) :

```
select distinct
referenced_database_name,
referenced_entity_name,
referenced_minor_name,
SUBSTRING(c.value,CHARINDEX('on',value)+3,len(value)) split
,IIF(SUBSTRING(c.value,CHARINDEX('on',value)+3,len(value)) like '%'+CONCAT(referenced_entity_name,'.',referenced_minor_name)+'%',1,0) as clm
from sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.sp_test', 'OBJECT') a
left join sys.sysdepends b on OBJECT_NAME(depid) = a.referenced_entity_name
outer apply string_split(REPLACE(OBJECT_DEFINITION(id),'--*','/'),'/') c
where OBJECT_NAME(id) = 'sp_test' and c.value like '%join%' and referenced_minor_name is not null
```